# Any payment method supports verifying credit card with random amount？

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, payment-methods, credit-card

we have a magento2 website and have experienced a few fraud credit card payment issues, so we are looking for a credit card payment method with a verification step.

I don't know what this step is called exactly. It is like when a customer placing a big order, we firstly charge a random cents from his credit card and then let him verifying the amount to prove he is the card's owner, then he can place the order.

So what is this step's name?  and any plugin have this function?

Thanks.

Comment: The usual way to tackle this problem is to ask the CV number as well, which shifts the responsibility for fraud back to the customer. He either doesn't have it (which is the case often when dealing with stolen cards) or has it (and there is no possibility of chargeback, YMMV, check with the card provider).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is CV number the 3 digits at the back(CVV)? I am in Australia and here in most cases and for most banks, the card owner can always claim the money back if he can prove it was not him placed the order...LOL

Comment: My mistake, it is called CVV. I'd suggest you check back with your credit card provider or the credit card company itself, they are usually pretty helpful, maybe they know more.